# Flask: return different pages if url was accessed within the app

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I'm working with Flask and am stuck with this question.
My users' dashboards are located in `/user/<user>`

I know it is bad to do so but had no idea about how to do it another way.

The question is, is there any way to return different pages if the url was accessed within my app or typed in browser search?

In other words, if a user was redirected to this page, the page of his dashboard should be returned. But if a user him-/herself typed this URL, the page of login should be returned.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to redirect unauthenticated users to the login page just use a decorator. Are you using `flask-login`?

Comment: This seems to be an [x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe the original problem instead of your attempted solution.

Comment: as @Selcuk mentioned you could use view decorators ... [see here for more](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/viewdecorators/#login-required-decorator)

Comment: @Selcuk, no I'm not. I just created two templates called login.html and signup.html, and after filling the form in them, the user is redirected to ```/user/<user>```

Comment: In any case, trusting the browser history would be a very fragile method. You should set a session cookie or similar to keep the user logged in, or even better, use a battle tested third party framework such as `flask-login`.

Comment: @Selcuk, I see, thanks a lot